# how can I deal with static files in different server

Tags: nginx

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
 }

upstream another_server {
    server 192.168.128.11;
}

server {
    server_name test.com;
    listen 80;


    location       / {
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location    ~ \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|mp4|json) {
        root     /www/app;
        try_files $uri /$1/$2.$4;
    }

    location ~ /anotherapp {
        proxy_pass http://another_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I have two server in different machines.I don't know how to deal with the static files in another_server.

When I get the `test.com/anotherapp/index.js` resoure ,but it return the files in app_server but not in another_app server.

The question is how can I deal with the static files in another_app server

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression `location` statements are evaluated in order until a matching regular expression is found.

So `/anotherapp/index.js` matches `\.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|mp4|json)` before it matches `/anotherapp`.

You have two options:

Either, reverse the order of the regular expression `location` blocks, so that `location ~ /anotherapp` is encountered first.

Or, use a prefix `location` with the `^~` modifier instead (which will always take precedence over any regular expression `location`), for example:

```
location ^~ /anotherapp { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.